# Country code select dropdown issue with countries having same country code

Tags: javascript, html, css, country-codes

I have a country code select dropdown in React. Recently I came to know that the USA and Canada have the same country code. The problem is whenever I select either Canada or the USA, the USA always gets selected as both of them have a common value "1". I also have to pass and receive this data from the back-end which also makes this even more complicated.

What is the way forward? Can I write '1' as '01', and is it valid?

```
<option  value="1">USA (+1)</option>
<option  value="1">Canada (+1)</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run into this more than once: for instance, Kazakhstan and Russia both use +7 ([there may be others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes), but I'm not sure).

I would recommend keeping a mapping of these on the server instead, and setting the values in your React app as the [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes), or really using any unique country ID you'd like that is saved on the server. Then, you could set this code or ID as the `value`, and when you submit the form, let the server determine what the calling code is.

Answer (score 0):

This works as designed.  You can use a different value as you speculated.  You could also remove the value attribute, in which case the text is being passed to the server i.e. `USA (+1)`.  As you encode both the country and prefix in the text, you could extract it, or have a suitable mapping on the server side that maps a text to both a country and prefix.